# java8 -XX:+UseCompressedOops -XX:ObjectAlignmentInBytes=16

Tags: java-8

So, I'm trying to run some simple code, jdk-8, output via jol

```
    System.out.println(VMSupport.vmDetails());
    Integer i = new Integer(23);
    System.out.println(ClassLayout.parseInstance(i)
            .toPrintable());
```

**The first attempt is to run it with compressed oops disabled and compressed klass also on 64-bit JVM.**

```
-XX:-UseCompressedOops -XX:-UseCompressedClassPointers
```

The output, pretty much expected is :

```
Running 64-bit HotSpot VM.
Objects are 8 bytes aligned.

java.lang.Integer object internals:
OFFSET  SIZE  TYPE DESCRIPTION                    VALUE
  0     4       (object header)                01 00 00 00 (00000001 00000000 00000000 00000000) (1)
  4     4       (object header)                00 00 00 00 (00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000) (0)
  8     4       (object header)                48 33 36 97 (01001000 00110011 00110110 10010111) (-1758055608)
 12     4       (object header)                01 00 00 00 (00000001 00000000 00000000 00000000) (1)
 16     4   int Integer.value                  23
 20     4       (loss due to the next object alignment)

Instance size: 24 bytes (reported by Instrumentation API)
Space losses: 0 bytes internal + 4 bytes external = 4 bytes total
```

That makes sense : 8 bytes klass word + 8 bytes mark word + 4 bytes for the actual value and 4 for padding (to align on 8 bytes) = 24 bytes.

**The second attempt it to run it with compressed oops enabled compressed klass also on 64-bit JVM.**

Again, the output is pretty much understandable :

```
Running 64-bit HotSpot VM.
Using compressed oop with 3-bit shift.
Using compressed klass with 3-bit shift.
Objects are 8 bytes aligned.

OFFSET  SIZE  TYPE DESCRIPTION                    VALUE
  0     4       (object header)                01 00 00 00 (00000001 00000000 00000000 00000000) (1)
  4     4       (object header)                00 00 00 00 (00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000) (0)
  8     4       (object header)                f9 33 01 f8 (11111001 00110011 00000001 11111000) (-134138887)
 12     4   int Dummy.i                        42
 Instance size: 16 bytes (reported by Instrumentation API).
```

4 bytes compressed oop (klass word) + 8 bytes mark word + 4 bytes for the value + no space loss = 16 bytes.

**The thing that does NOT make sense to me is this use-case:**

```
 -XX:+UseCompressedOops -XX:+UseCompressedClassPointers -XX:ObjectAlignmentInBytes=16
```

The output is this:

```
 Running 64-bit HotSpot VM.
 Using compressed oop with 4-bit shift.
 Using compressed klass with 0x0000001000000000 base address and 0-bit shift.
```

I was really expecting to both be "4-bit shift". Why they are not?

**EDIT**
The second example is run with :

```
 XX:+UseCompressedOops -XX:+UseCompressedClassPointers
```

And the third one with :

```
 -XX:+UseCompressedOops -XX:+UseCompressedClassPointers -XX:ObjectAlignmentInBytes=16
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I will try to extend a little bit on the answer provided by Alexey as some things might not be obvious.

Following Alexey suggestion, if we search the source code of OpenJDK for where compressed klass bit shift value is assigned, we will find the following code in metaspace.cpp:

```
void Metaspace::set_narrow_klass_base_and_shift(address metaspace_base, address cds_base) {
// some code removed 
if ((uint64_t)(higher_address - lower_base) <= UnscaledClassSpaceMax) {
  Universe::set_narrow_klass_shift(0);
} else {
  assert(!UseSharedSpaces, "Cannot shift with UseSharedSpaces");
  Universe::set_narrow_klass_shift(LogKlassAlignmentInBytes);
}
```

As we can see, the class shift can either be 0(or basically no shifting) or 3 bits, because LogKlassAlignmentInBytes is a constant defined in globalDefinitions.hpp:

```
const int LogKlassAlignmentInBytes = 3;
```

So, the answer to your quetion:

> I was really expecting to both be "4-bit shift". Why they are not?

is that ObjectAlignmentInBytes does not have any effect on compressed class pointers alignment in the metaspace which is always 8bytes.

Of course this conclusion does not answer the question:

*"Why when using -XX:ObjectAlignmentInBytes=16 with -XX:+UseCompressedClassPointers the narrow klass shift becomes zero? Also, without shifting how can the JVM reference the class space with 32-bit references, if the heap is 4GBytes or more?"*

We already know that the class space is allocated on top of the java heap and can be up to 3G in size. With that in mind let's make a few tests. -XX:+UseCompressedOops -XX:+UseCompressedClassPointers are enabled by default, so we can eliminate these for conciseness.

**Test 1: Defaults - 8 Bytes aligned**

```
$ java -XX:ObjectAlignmentInBytes=8 -XX:+UnlockDiagnosticVMOptions -XX:+PrintCompressedOopsMode -version

heap address: 0x00000006c0000000, size: 4096 MB, zero based Compressed Oops

Narrow klass base: 0x0000000000000000, Narrow klass shift: 3
Compressed class space size: 1073741824 Address: 0x00000007c0000000 Req Addr: 0x00000007c0000000
```

Notice that the heap starts at address 0x00000006c0000000 in the virtual space and has a size of 4GBytes. Let's jump by 4Gbytes from where the heap starts and we land just where class space begins.

```
0x00000006c0000000 + 0x0000000100000000 = 0x00000007c0000000
```

The class space size is 1Gbyte, so let's jump by another 1Gbyte:

```
0x00000007c0000000 + 0x0000000040000000 = 0x0000000800000000
```

and we land just below 32Gbytes. With a 3 bits class space shifting the JVM is able to reference the entire class space, although it's at the limit (intentionally).

**Test 2: 16 bytes aligned**

```
java -XX:ObjectAlignmentInBytes=16 -XX:+UnlockDiagnosticVMOptions -XX:+PrintCompressedOopsMode -version

heap address: 0x0000000f00000000, size: 4096 MB, zero based Compressed Oops

Narrow klass base: 0x0000001000000000, Narrow klass shift: 0
Compressed class space size: 1073741824 Address: 0x0000001000000000 Req Addr: 0x0000001000000000
```

This time we can observe that the heap address is different, but let's try the same steps:

```
0x0000000f00000000 + 0x0000000100000000 = 0x0000001000000000
```

This time around heap space ends just below 64GBytes virtual space boundary and the class space is allocated above 64Gbyte boundary. Since class space can use only 3 bits shifting, how can the JVM reference the class space located above 64Gbyte? The key is:

```
Narrow klass base: 0x0000001000000000
```

The JVM still uses 32 bit compressed pointers for the class space, but when encoding and decoding these, it will always add 0x0000001000000000 base to the compressed reference instead of using shifting. Note, that this approach works as long as the referenced chunk of memory is lower than 4Gbytes (the limit for 32 bits references). Considering that the class space can have a maximum of 3Gbytes we are comfortably within the limits.

**3: 16 bytes aligned, pin heap base at 8g**

```
$ java -XX:ObjectAlignmentInBytes=16 -XX:HeapBaseMinAddress=8g -XX:+UnlockDiagnosticVMOptions -XX:+PrintCompressedOopsMode -version

heap address: 0x0000000200000000, size: 4096 MB, zero based Compressed Oops

Narrow klass base: 0x0000000000000000, Narrow klass shift: 3
Compressed class space size: 1073741824 Address: 0x0000000300000000 Req Addr: 0x0000000300000000
```

In this test we are still keeping the -XX:ObjectAlignmentInBytes=16, but also asking the JVM to allocate the heap at the 8th GByte in the virtual address space using -XX:HeapBaseMinAddress=8g JVM argument. The class space will begin at 12th GByte in the virtual address space and 3 bits shifting is more than enough to reference it.

Hopefully, these tests and their results answer the question:

> "Why when using -XX:ObjectAlignmentInBytes=16 with -XX:+UseCompressedClassPointers the narrow klass shift becomes zero? Also, without shifting how can the JVM reference the class space with 32-bit references, if the heap is 4GBytes or more?"

Answer (score 8):

Answers to these questions are mostly easy to figure out when looking into OpenJDK code.

For example, grep for "UseCompressedClassPointers", this will get you to [arguments.cpp](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk9/jdk9/hotspot/file/5d17092b6917/src/share/vm/runtime/arguments.cpp#l1797):

```
// Check the CompressedClassSpaceSize to make sure we use compressed klass ptrs.
if (UseCompressedClassPointers) {
  if (CompressedClassSpaceSize > KlassEncodingMetaspaceMax) {
    warning("CompressedClassSpaceSize is too large for UseCompressedClassPointers");
    FLAG_SET_DEFAULT(UseCompressedClassPointers, false);
  }
}
```

Okay, interesting, there is "CompressedClassSpaceSize"? Grep for its definition, it's in [globals.hpp](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk9/jdk9/hotspot/file/5d17092b6917/src/share/vm/runtime/globals.hpp#l3309):

```
  product(size_t, CompressedClassSpaceSize, 1*G,                            \
          "Maximum size of class area in Metaspace when compressed "        \
          "class pointers are used")                                        \
          range(1*M, 3*G)                                                   \
```

Aha, so the class area is in Metaspace, and it takes somewhere between 1 Mb and 3 Gb of space. Let's grep for "CompressedClassSpaceSize" usages, because that will take us to actual code that handles it, say in [metaspace.cpp](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk9/jdk9/hotspot/file/5d17092b6917/src/share/vm/memory/metaspace.cpp#l3075):

```
// For UseCompressedClassPointers the class space is reserved above
// the top of the Java heap. The argument passed in is at the base of
// the compressed space.
void Metaspace::initialize_class_space(ReservedSpace rs) {
```

So, compressed classes are allocated in a smaller class space outside the Java heap, which does not require shifting -- even 3 gigabytes is small enough to use only the lowest 32 bits.

Comment: this is a great explanation, but there are minor things I would like to further understand with your help. So, there is a space in the metaspace (I know it's off-heap), called CompressedClassSpace, and it's maximum size is 3G, and 32 bit are more then enough to reference those 3G, so no need for shifting, right? If so, then why would you still shift in the second example then?

Comment: AFAIU, without `UseCompressedClassPointers` the class mirrors are still allocated on heap, and the references to them are compressed as the references to other objects. That is why they need the 3-bit shift, as other ordinary Java objects.

Comment: actually if u look at the second and third example, the ONLY difference is in the  -XX:ObjectAlignmentInBytes=16. Either 8 or 16, compressed class references are ALWAYS on, this is confusing.

Comment: I am confused what are the command line flags for your "second" example. Please spell them out in the question.

Comment: Noticed something interesting when running the same code snippet with and without -Djol.tryWithSudo=true. So the output without jol.tryWithSudo: `Running 64-bit HotSpot VM.
Using compressed oop with 4-bit shift.
Using compressed klass with 4-bit shift.
` and the output with jol.tryWithSudo=true: `Running 64-bit HotSpot VM.
Using compressed oop with 4-bit shift.
Using compressed klass with 0x0000001000000000 base address and 0-bit shift.
`. -XX:ObjectAlignmentInBytes=16 is set, UseCompressedOops and UseCompressedClassPointers not set and are on by default. Hope this helps.