# optimize nifi performance by changing heap size < 32 gb and leverage oops compression

Tags: java, jvm, compression, apache-nifi

Can i tweak bootstrap.conf to start nifi with heap size <32GB so that [oops compression](https://wiki.openjdk.java.net/display/HotSpot/CompressedOops) happens automatically. We are currently at :

`​java -Xmx32768m -XX:+PrintFlagsFinal 2> /dev/null | grep UseCompressedOops` -- returns false

From bootstrap.conf:

```
   java.arg.3=-Xmx32768m
```

And our heap utilization is :

```
"heapUtilization":"86%"
```

​Can Nifi performance improve if we leverage oops compression ? What other parameters should i monitor and improve upon ?

EDIT 1: Also, using large heap sizes can delay the GC and hence the dataflows. Is there a optimized heapsize that everyone is already using on production ?

Comment: *"Can Nifi performance improve if we leverage oops compression ?"* - Probably, but not necessarily. 31G is often better than 32G, but this depends on what metrics you consider when comparing performance.

Comment: *"Is there a optimized heapsize that everyone is already using on production"* - No. Different applications and workloads obviously require different configuration.

Comment: You can also use `-XX:ObjectAlignmentInBytes=16` to be able to use compressed oops with more than 32GiB (up to 64GiB).

Comment: @Holger oh my! just today was re-reading... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35411754/java8-xxusecompressedoops-xxobjectalignmentinbytes-16

Comment: Did you choose 32GB because you were getting OutOfMemory exceptions at lower sizes? Generally I'd suggest trying to start out with smaller heap sizes like 8GB and only increasing beyond that if you actually hit OOM

Comment: @Eugene upvoted that question. That question is an eye opener. Thanks for that link.

Comment: @Holger I will definitely try that first thing tomorrow morning.  Thanks everyone for sharing your knowledge. I will be back with the findings.