Why is the MaxHeapSize of my Java app in a Kubernetes container 20GB less than I had expected?
I have a Tomcat container with a memory request of 62000Mi. The JAVA_OPTS environment variable contains -XX:InitialRAMPercentage=50.0 and -XX:MaxRAMPercentage=80.0.
I was expecting the MaxHeapSize to be 80% of the memory request so ~50GB however the actual MaxHeapSize is ~30GB so I am missing ~20GB.
What could be the reason(s) that I don't get the expected MaxHeapSize? Is it feasible to use MaxRAMPercentage on Kubernetes, or should I stick to Xmx?
This is on Java 11. The Kubernetes worker node has 64GB memory and is hosted on VMWare with dynamic memory allocation.

MaxRAMPercentage is setting the total JVM memory size, not the Java heap size.  The "missing" space is actually used for things that are not directly available heap space; e.g. static code & native libraries, bytecode annd JIT compiled code, direct buffers, heap overheaps, etcetera.

It is better to use MaxRAMPercentage.  It makes the JVM aware that it has a limit for everything that it must not go over.  However, I don't know if it makes sense for a K8s worker node to be running on a hypervisor that could be over-committing its RAM.

It could be that your JVM runs with compressed oops which by default limits the maximum heap size to 32GB. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35411754/java8-xxusecompressedoops-xxobjectalignmentinbytes-16 for more explanations and some options.
